# Custom Auth in Firechat UI Not Populating UID Correctly

Tags: firebase

I'm using a custom authantification token to initiate FirechatUI which is failing with  **Uncaught Error: FirechatUI: Missing required argument `el`
joe:81 Object**

I suspect this is because the authData's uid field is null (auth: "{"uid":"joe"}"..."uid": null)

```
chatRef.onAuth(function(authData) {
  if (authData) {
    console.log(authData);
    var chat = new FirechatUI(chatRef, document.getElementById('firechat-wrapper'));
    chat.setUser(authData.uid,authData[authData.provider].displayName);
  }
 }
});
```

I create the auth token in GoLang as follows

```
func genChatToken(username string) (string, error) {
  token := jwt.New(jwt.SigningMethodHS256)
  token.Claims["v"] = 0
  token.Claims["iat"] = time.Now().Unix()

  json, err := json.Marshal(map[string]string{
    "uid": username,
  })
  if err != nil {
    return "", err
  }
  token.Claims["d"] = string(json)

return token.SignedString([]byte("..."))
```

}

And authanticate as

```
chatRef.authWithCustomToken({{ .params.token }}, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Stacktrace below

```
firechat.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: FirechatUI: Missing required argument `el`
firechat.min.js:2 t
joe:82 (anonymous function)firebase-debug.js:5400
fb.core.util.EventEmitter.onfirebase-debug.js:11989
Firebase.onAuthjoe:79 (anonymous function)
```

Comment: John, [try your compiled token out here](http://jsfiddle.net/firebase/XDXu5/embedded/result/) and see how it parses according to Firebase. Also, include the stack trace from Firechat if possible. Assuming that's JavaScript, you can use `firebase-debug.js` in place of `firebase.js` to get a more meaningful stack trace.

Comment: Thanks @kato.  Added stacktrace above. And the token authenticates to ({"d":"{\"uid\":\"joe\"}","iat":1426267318,"uid":"joe","v":0}) But I think the problem is because you need to create the user before logging them in.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "create the user", but when generating your own auth tokens, you just call authWithCustomToken()--there's nothing to create, by signing the token you validate that the user exists and is valid. Maybe you should include your auth code as it seems relevant.

Comment: What I don't understand is if the user field has to be populates somewhere already.  If I try to authenticate a user that doesn't eist is it created?

Comment: There is no user. It's a signed token providing access. If you are creating the token, you decide what that means. Presumably, if you create a custom token then you've already checked to see if the user exists in some system. You are verifying the valid token, this is all your purview. If you don't understand this process, then you probably want the integrated auth rather than creating your own tokens.

Comment: Thanks @kato.  The confusion is I'm using firechat not just firebase, and firechat has its own user state in addition to my application.  So firechat just logs in as 'undefined' instead of the desired user.  As in

Comment: Attempt to read /chat/users/undefined with `auth=Success("{\"displayName\":\"joe\",\"id\":\"joe\",\"name\":\"joe\",\"uid\":\"joe\"}")`

Answer (score 0):

The 'el' parameter refers to the div that FirechatUI injects the chat window into. If your 'firechat-wrapper' div does not exist when you instantiate FirechatUI then it will throw this error.